# Wix installer CAQuietExec custom action

Tags: .net, installation, wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to execute a custom action in a Wix installer, to grant permission to bind to a HTTP socket, on Windows Server 2008. However the installer isn't quite working.

```
<CustomAction Id="GrantHttpPermission_Cmd" Property="GrantHttpPermission" Value="&quot;[SystemFolder]netsh.exe http add urlacl url=http://+:8732/ user=Service_account&quot;" Execute="immediate"/>
<CustomAction Id="GrantHttpPermission" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no"/>

...

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="GrantHttpPermission_Cmd" After="CostFinalize"/>
  <Custom Action="GrantHttpPermission" After="ConfigureUsers">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Running the installer in debug mode I get the following failure. I also tried running the installer as Administrator, with the same output

```
MSI (s) (14:20) [11:03:00:440]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=GrantHttpPermission,ActionType=3073,Source=BinaryData,Target=CAQuietExec,CustomActionData="C:\Windows\SysWOW64\netsh.exe http add urlacl url=http://+:8732/ user=Service_account")
MSI (s) (14:24) [11:03:00:440]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIF794.tmp, Entrypoint: CAQuietExec
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80070002: Command failed to execute.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80070002: CAQuietExec Failed
CustomAction GrantHttpPermission returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 11:03:00: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
```

Can anyone shed any light on what's up with that command?

Comment: Have you tried to run your command in a usual console? Does it execute fine? Take a look at the form it expands to (in the log file), and try to run the same manually.

Comment: Yan, yes, it appears to execute correctly from the command line. But only as administrator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out it was to do with correctly quoting the command. The `GrantHttpPermission_Cmd` line needed the " moving to around the executable, not the entire command, and the `[SystemFolder]` part was not required. Final command looked like this:

```
<CustomAction Id="GrantHttpPermission_Cmd" Property="GrantHttpPermission" Value="&quot;netsh.exe&quot; http add urlacl url=http://+:8732/ user=Service_account" Execute="immediate"/>
```

All the other commands were the same.

Comment: Good to know it was that simple. Now when you found it yourself, you'll never forget it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<CustomAction Id="GrantHttpPermission_Cmd" Property="GrantHttpPermission" Value="[SystemFolder]netsh.exe http add urlacl url=http://+:8732/ user=Service_account" Execute="immediate"/>
```

If you enclose the value in quotes (&quot;), you will get an invalid command line:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe http add urlacl url=http://+:8732/ user=Service_account"
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but this causes the installer to complain that the command is not initiated with a quote.